Selenium-webdriver: Process.spawn can't see existing /root/.webdrivers/chromedriver
Creating my first Selenium test, I get the following excpetion
Error:                                                                                                                 
LoginsTest#test_login:                                                                                                 
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - /root/.webdrivers/chromedriver                                              
    test/system/logins_test.rb:6:in `block in <class:LoginsTest>'                                               
                                                                                                                       
Error:                                                     
LoginsTest#test_login:                                                                                                 
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - /root/.webdrivers/chromedriver                                        
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/child_process.rb:58:in `spawn'      
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/child_process.rb:58:in `start'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/service_manager.rb:104:in `start_process'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/service_manager.rb:57:in `block in start'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/socket_lock.rb:42:in `locked'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/service_manager.rb:55:in `start'
    <internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'                                                                                      
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/service.rb:92:in `launch'           
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:328:in `service_url'      
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/local_driver.rb:28:in `initialize_local_driver'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/chrome/driver.rb:34:in `initialize'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:47:in `new'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:47:in `for'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:89:in `for'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-3.40.0/lib/capybara/selenium/driver.rb:75:in `browser'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-7.2.1.2/lib/action_dispatch/system_testing/driver.rb:57:in `block in register_selenium'
    <internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-7.2.1.2/lib/action_dispatch/system_testing/driver.rb:56:in `register_selenium'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-7.2.1.2/lib/action_dispatch/system_testing/driver.rb:43:in `block in register'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-3.40.0/lib/capybara/session.rb:106:in `driver'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-3.40.0/lib/capybara/session.rb:92:in `initialize'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-3.40.0/lib/capybara.rb:422:in `new'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-3.40.0/lib/capybara.rb:422:in `block in session_pool'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-3.40.0/lib/capybara.rb:317:in `current_session'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-3.40.0/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:46:in `page'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-7.2.1.2/lib/action_dispatch/system_testing/test_helpers/screenshot_helper.rb:116:in `save_image'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-7.2.1.2/lib/action_dispatch/system_testing/test_helpers/screenshot_helper.rb:46:in `take_screenshot'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-7.2.1.2/lib/action_dispatch/system_testing/test_helpers/screenshot_helper.rb:56:in `take_failed_screenshot'
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-7.2.1.2/lib/action_dispatch/system_testing/test_helpers/setup_and_teardown.rb:10:in `before_teardown'

If I put a debugger call in in child_process.rb:
        @pid = Process.spawn(*@command, options)                                                                                                                                                                                              
        WebDriver.logger.debug("  -> pid: #{@pid}", id: :process)                                                                                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
        Process.detach(@pid) if detach                                                                                                                                                                                                        
      rescue => e                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
        debugger if Rails.env.test?                                                                                                                                                                                                           
        nil                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        raise e                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
      end

The file in @command clearly exists:
(ruby) @command
["/root/.webdrivers/chromedriver", "--port=9515"]
(rdbg) options
{[:out, :err]=>"/dev/null", :pgroup=>true}
(ruby) `ls -l /root/.webdrivers/chromedriver`
"-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root      15039112 Oct 30 00:35 /root/.webdrivers/chromedriver\n"

And I am running as the right user:
(ruby) `whoami`
"root\n"

What am I missing?

The error suggests that driver file does not exist in the /root/.webdrivers/ directory ("/root/.webdrivers/chromedriver"). Since you are using Selenium 4.2, compatible driver file is required. Either use webdrivermanager (which automatically picks the dirver file and then you do not need to explicitly define the driver path) or use Selenium 4.6 or greater, which will handle the driver files automatically

As suggested in a blog post by Ryan Bigg, installing some missing apk packages fixed it
~/.webdrivers # apk add gcompat glib nss libxcb libgcc
(1/3) Installing musl-obstack (1.2.3-r2)
(2/3) Installing libucontext (1.2-r3)
(3/3) Installing gcompat (1.1.0-r4)
OK: 1294 MiB in 258 packages
~/.webdrivers # ./chromedriver 
Starting ChromeDriver 114.0.5735.90 (386bc09e8f4f2e025eddae123f36f6263096ae49-refs/branch-heads/5735@{#1052}) on port 9515
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
[1730321023.240][SEVERE]: bind() failed: Address not available (99)
ChromeDriver was started successfully.

Getting a different error now in systems tests, but this did solve the "file not found" error.
